# What is the meaning of this multi commodity formulation VRP in LINGO

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, vehicle-routing

Can someone tell me what is the meaning of this multi commodity flow formulation that I got in LINGO ? I have the brief explanation about the model but don't quite understand the logic behind, here is the information and the code:

```
Decision Variable:
Flo( i, j, c, k) = amount of commodity destined for node c, 
                      carried from node i to node j on vehicle type k; 

! Model multi-commodity flow;
! Cannot have flow within a single node;
  @FOR( Set( j) :
     @SUM( Vehicle( k): @SUM( Set( c): Flo( j, j, c, k))) = 0;
    );

! Flow into node j of commodity c = demand for c at j + flow out;
@FOR( Vehicle( k):
  @FOR( Set( j) | j #NE# Depot:
    @FOR( Set( c) | c #NE# j #AND# c #NE# Depot:
   [CFLO]  @SUM( Set( i) | i #NE# j: Flo( i, j, c, k)) =
           @SUM( Set( i) | i #NE# j: Flo( j, i, c, k)) 
        );
      );
    );

  @FOR( Set( j) | j #NE# Depot:
  ! Flow entering j of commodity for j;
   [DFLOE]  @SUM( SxSxSxV( i, j, c, k) | i #NE# j #AND# j #EQ# c: Flo( i, j, c, k)) = Demand( j);
  ! Flow departing j of commodity for j;
   [DFLOD]  @SUM( SxSxSxV( j, i, c, k) | i #NE# j #AND# j #EQ# c: Flo( j, i, c, k)) = 0;  
     );

! Only source of supply is the Depot;
 @FOR( Set( c):
   @SUM( SxSxSxV( i, j, c, k) | i #EQ# Depot: Flo( i, j, c, k)) = Demand( c)
     );

! Any flow on arc i, j of commodity c means arc i, j, k is used;
  @FOR( SxSxSxV( i, j, c, k) | j #NE# Depot #AND# c #NE# Depot:
 [FORCE]    Flo( i, j, c, k) <= Demand( c) * x( i, j, k)
      );
```

I have tested with small nodes of 3:
Here is what I got:

> Selected route: 1 - 3 - 2 - 1 (1 is depot)
> `x(1,3,1) = 1`
> `x(3,2,1) = 1`
> `x(2,1,1) = 1`

And the flow variables:

```
Flo(1,3,2,1) = 9
Flo(1,3,3,1) = 7
Flo(3,2,2,1) = 9
```

Is the flow not balanced? I mean why is there not have another 7 in there?

Answer (score 1):

Flo(i,j,c,k) is the amount of flow destined for node c that is carried by vehicle k from node i to node j. So Flo(1,3,3,1) is the amount *destined for node 3* that is carried on vehicle 1 from node 1 to node 3. Since node 3 is its destination, there is no reason for it to be carried out of node 3.

Comment: Why they carry 9 on the node of 2 ? Flo(3,2,2,1) = 9

Comment: Because node 2 has a demand for 9 (or more)?

Comment: is it not fulfilled with f(1,3,2,1) = 9. The demand of node 2 is 9 units and the demand for node 3 is 7 units

Comment: 9 units of whatever node 2 ordered flow from node 1 to node 3 [Flo(1,3,2,1) = 9] and then from node 3 to node 2 [Flo(3,2,2,1) = 9]. 7 units of whatever node 3 ordered flow directly from node 1 to node 3 [Flo(1,3,3,1) = 7].